# ClassFactory cannot supply requested class - WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")

Tags: vbscript

I get the error "xpto.vbs(2, 1) ClassFactory cannot supply requested class" when I run the code line "WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")" on the folowing code:

```
Dim oShell
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
oShell.run "cmd /K CD C:\ & Dir"
Set oShell = Nothing
```

I have version 5.1 of vbscript on a windows2000 o.s.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I would install Windows Script 5.6:

[Windows Script 5.6 for Windows XP and Windows 2000](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C717D943-7E4B-4622-86EB-95A22B832CAA&displaylang=en)